# Llamar variable que esta dentro de una funcion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(function(){

        var a;

        $('p').each(function(){
        a = $(this).text();     
        });

       alert(a); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>a = 1</p>
<p>a = 2</p>
<p>a = 3</p>
<p>a = 4</p>
<p>a = 5</p>
```

Hola a todos, tengo este sencillo html y script js, he declarado una variable global que es igual al texto de cada elemento p. Mi problema es que la alerta solo me muestra el texto del primer párrafo y no todos. Si meto la alerta en la función each, ahora si me muestra el texto de todos los elementos

. ¿Cómo muestro el texto de todos los elementos p con la alerta fuera de la función each? .Gracias

Comment: Estaba realizando un código, y tuve problemas para llamar una var dentro de una función, entonces tuve que copiar la funcion dos veces y crear de nuevo la variable. Cuando repites las cosas es porque algo andas haciendo mal. Por eso estoy intentando crear una variable global en la cuál se pueda acceder a cada función sin estar repitiendo, por eso puse como ejemplo este código.

Comment: :'c creo q tienes razon, el codigo funciona correctamente, pero a simple viste se ve tosco repetir mas de una vez, en fin, gracias por responder a mi pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás tratando de mostrar el texto de una lista de nodos, dado lo cual yo pensaría en:

- Seleccionar todos los elementos en común (*en este caso tal vez por su nombre de etiqueta*)
- Iterar dichos elementos
- Por dentro de la iteración, cuando recuperas a cada elemento entonces imprimir en un *alert* el atributo deseado

Así:

```html
    <p>a = 1</p>
    <p>a = 2</p>
    <p>a = 3</p>
    <p>a = 4</p>
    <p>a = 5</p>
    
    <script>
      let parrafos = document.querySelectorAll('p');
      
      parrafos.forEach((parrafo) => {
        alert(parrafo.innerText);
      })
    </script>
```

Por otro lado no le veo sentido a lo que propones, es decir iterar los elementos almacenar su valor en una variable y posterior por fuera del ciclo tratar de imprimir su valor por que:

- La variable que declares por fuera del ciclo y que iguales con un valor por dentro de este obtendrá el valor del último elemento iterado
- Como *ya te proponían antes* entonces debes ir acumulando en dicha variable
- Una vez que hiciste dicha acumulación podrás imprimir por fuera del ciclo a la variable pero en concencuencia todos los valores almacenados saldrán en un solo alert

```html
    <p>a = 1</p>
    <p>a = 2</p>
    <p>a = 3</p>
    <p>a = 4</p>
    <p>a = 5</p>
    
    <script>
      let parrafos = document.querySelectorAll('p');
      let valores = '';
      parrafos.forEach((parrafo) => {
        valores += parrafo.innerText;
      })
      alert(valores);
    </script>
```

Una *solución (**poco práctica**)* sería:

- Obtener la lista de nodos de los elementos deseados
- Indicar en `alerts` por separado la impresión de cada uno de estos por el índice que ocupan y el atributo deseado

```html
    <p>a = 1</p>
    <p>a = 2</p>
    <p>a = 3</p>
    <p>a = 4</p>
    <p>a = 5</p>
    
    <script>
      let parrafos = document.querySelectorAll('p');
      
      alert(parrafos[0].innerText);
      alert(parrafos[1].innerText);
      alert(parrafos[2].innerText);
      alert(parrafos[3].innerText);
      alert(parrafos[4].innerText);
    </script>
```

> Pero como claramente notas esto último *aunque pueda funcionar* no tiene sentido por que a medida que la lista de nodos crezca se volverá poco funcional y nada sostenible, cosa que como te expongo en la primer propuesta solventamos sin importar la cantidad de nodos que existan en la variable.

Comment: Buena solución muy bien explicada ! Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene un bucle que se ejecuta por cada `<p>` que encuentra. En cada iteración (cada una de las 5 veces), la variable `a` se sobreescribe. Ese es el problema, siempre se va a quedar con el último valor.

La forma de solucionarlo sería concatenar el valor que tiene `a` con el nuevo valor:

```
a = a + $(this).text();
// que es lo mismo que:
// a += $(this).text();
```

---

**Pero** los bucles ya están encapsulados en funciones cuando estamos con jQuery. Así obtenemos el texto concatenado de todos los elementos `<p>`:

```
$('p').text();
```

o generar un array con `$.map()` que tendrá cada uno de los textos:

```
a = $.map($('p'), $.text);
```

y luego lo recorremos para mostrar con alert:

```js
$(function(){
  //lleva el texto de cada elemento a un array
  var a = $.map($('p'), $.text);

  //bucle por cada elemento del array
  for (let texto of a) {
    alert(texto);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>a = 1</p>
<p>a = 2</p>
<p>a = 3</p>
<p>a = 4</p>
<p>a = 5</p>
```

Aunque, ¿para qué querrías molestar tanto a alguien con 5 alertas?